# How to send POST in angular5 with multiple params?

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular5, angular2-services

I'm working in angular5 simple project (front end) and back end(spring boot) , i want to send a post request to the api rest with 2 parameters idPerson , and idProject , so the api rest can affect the project to the selected Person , i tried doing this in a service with POST but it's not possible .

This is the code for ProjectService.ts

```
    addProjToClient(idPerson:number,idProject:number){
    if(this.authService.getToken()==null) {
      this.authService.loadToken();
    }
    return this.http.post(this.host+"/saveProjectToClient",idPerson,idProject,{headers:new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.authService.getToken()})});

  }
```

It's not possible to send more than 2 parametrs in http Post , i use httpClient .

Any idea on how to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument to `http.post` is the body of the post request. Just put both values in the body and then get them out of the body on the server.

```js
return this.http.post(this.host+"/saveProjectToClient", {
  idPerson,
  idProject,
}, {
  headers:new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': this.authService.getToken()
  })
});
```

On the server (Springboot)

```java
public class Dto {
    private String idPerson;
    private String idProject;
}


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ExampleController {

   @PostMapping("/saveProjectToClient")
   public ResponseEntity postController(@RequestBody Dto dto) {
      System.out.print("Person Id was: ");
      System.out.println(dto.idPerson);
      System.out.print("Project Id was: ");
      System.out.println(dto.idProject);

      return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to get them out of the body on the server ? i'm using spring boot

Comment: I have never done Spring boot before but I updated my answer with my best guess.

Comment: back again i tried this , i don't know why but it seems that the ResponseEntity is not reachable . there is no error at the same time back end doesn't receive the post request.

Comment: This is a good solution. Like dEst12ZER mentioned the call will never reach backend. you will get an http 400.
Technically Spring framework will not take inner classes as @RestBody parameters.

Comment: Http 400!
Spring framework will NOT take INNER classes as @RequestBody parameters.

Create a separate Dto class in your project DTO layer.

And in the Angular create a collection object which you can pass to the web service call...

myservicecall (idper, idpro) {

const myDto = {
  idPerson: idper,
  idProject: idpro,
};

return this.http.post(this.host+"/saveProjectToClient", myDto, {
  headers:new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': this.authService.getToken()
  })
});

}

Answer (score 2):

Add all parameters in a json object, ex:
 `{ idPerson: 'personId', idProject: 'projectId'}`  as a second parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
generisiIOS(idtipkomitenta: number, idtipios: number, datumpreseka: Date, idkorisnika: number) {
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify({ idtipkomitenta, idtipios, datumpreseka, idkorisnika });
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/JSON' });
        return this._http.post<number>('faktura/generisiios', bodyString, { headers });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain this method ?

Comment: @dEs12ZER It is pretty self explanatory. You call service with (in this case 4 parameters). Since you are using POST they are put as JSON in body. I use http interceptors for token, so in my case I havent set token in header. On server side, you simply pick it from body and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
createRange(range: any, details: any): Observable { 
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    let body = JSON.stringify({ 'range': range, 'details': details }); 
    return this.httpClient.post(this.serviceURL + '/save', body, { headers });
}
```